# Markov models in time series prediction

Tags: time-series, markov-process

Markov models are good for analyzing sequential data. Hence they should be suitable for time series modeling. But what are some limitations of Markov models to be used for time series prediction?

Comment: Do you mean forecasting or prediction?

Comment: Forecasting and prediction are the same thing.